# What is the following error doing? I do not see any error with the bounds

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

The code has a header, implementation, and main files. 
It is supposed to increment the ASCII value of all characters in the string then return the character value associated with that ASCII value.

The code in question is as follows:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(letters); i++)
    {
        if ((int)letters.at(i) >= (int)'a' && (int)letters.at(i) <= (int)'z')
        {
            letters.at(i) = (((letters.at(i) - 'a') + 1) % 26 + 'a');
        }

        else if ((int)letters.at(i) >= (int)'A' && (int)letters.at(i) <= (int)'Z')
        {
            letters.at(i) = (((letters.at(i) - 'a') + 1) % 26 + 'A');
        }
    }
```

Unhandled exception at 0x750A3DB2 in HomeworkNine.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00EFF7E8. occurred

I do not see where the out of bounds is, since I thought the modulus would take care of that.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: `sizeof(letters)` -- *I do not see where the out of bounds is,* -- Well, if you don't know what `sizeof` does, then you won't see the error.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Prepending line `std::string letters("a");` reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I know, I wanted to give OP the chance to ask for **their** code, but as they dont seem to care too much I'll just fix it

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin well, no I wont, because it would render your answer unclear...

Comment: @idclev463035818 Hopefully, `HomeworkTen.exe` will be reproducible.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(letters)` is only right if `letters` is a plain array of `char`, which it cannot be because plain arrays don't have `at` member function. `at` member functions in the C++ standard library compare with `size()` for random-access sequences and throw `std::out_of_range` if the index is not less than `size()`. You need to replace `sizeof(letters)` with `letters.size()`.

Note that the upper case branch has a bug that is does `-'a'` and then `+'A'`.

Those casts to `int` are unnecessary because the compiler does them for you (or `unsigned` if `char` is unsigned on your platform). The built-in arithmetic operators and comparisons work only on `int` or larger types, see [Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Alternative C++11 version:

```
std::string letters("abc..zABC..Z");
for(auto& c : letters) {
    if(std::isalpha(c))
        c += std::tolower(c) != 'z' ? 1 : ('a' - 'z');
}
```